# Which table contains the data on the member group channel assignment privileges?

Tags: members, channel, member-management

I am looking at my database and have looked at these tables

```
exp_member
exp_member_data
exp_member_fields
exp_member_groups
```

I can’t find any information here about the channel assignment privileges of a member group.

The one where you have something like

```
Can post and edit entries in:  Foo    Yes      No      
Can post and edit entries in:  Bar    Yes     No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group_id is mapped to the channel_id in channel_member_groups

(an entry in this table means that 'YES' has been selected for that group/channel combination)